# Folder creation - from .bat file to powershell / sharepoint

Tags: powershell, batch-file, sharepoint, directory-structure

I use a .bat file to create folders listed in two .txt files and also for deleting empty folders. All works fine but now I need the same to work on sharepoint.

Can anyone describe how or if this can be done? I have read that maybe I need to find put about powershell?

The .bat file looks like this:

```
echo off
%CHCP 1252
mkdir C:\Temp\MStruktur
Copy "P:\folderstructure\Niv1.txt" "C:\Temp\MStruktur"
Copy "P:\folderstructure\Niv2.txt" "C:\Temp\MStruktur"

cls

REM -----checking for empty characters
for %%a in (.) do set currentfolder=%%~na
if not "%currentfolder%"=="%currentfolder: =%" GOTO error


:home
echo "Folder structure menu:"
echo -------------------------------------
echo - 1 - create level 1
echo - 2 - create level 2
echo.
echo - S - Delete empty folders
echo.
echo - X - Exit
echo.

set /p web=Valg:
if "%web%"=="1" goto niv1
if "%web%"=="2" goto niv2
if "%web%"=="s" goto slet
if "%web%"=="x" goto slut
goto home

:niv1
cls
for /f %%i in (C:\Temp\MStruktur\niv1.txt) do mkdir %~dp0\%%i
echo.
echo Level 1 created
echo.
pause
exit

:niv2
cls
for /f %%i in (C:\Temp\MStruktur\niv2.txt) do mkdir %~dp0\%%i
echo.
echo Level 2 created
echo.
pause
exit
  
:slet
cls
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir %~dp0 /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"
echo.
echo Deleted empty folders
echo.
pause
exit

:error
cls
echo.
echo No blanks in folder name
echo.
pause
exit

:slut
RD /S /Q C:\Temp\MStruktur
exit
```

Comment: As long as the network drive is mounted correctly, Sharepoint should act exactly like any other folder.

Comment: So you mean that you would sync the drive to a local copy and run the .bat file from the normal explorer instead of on the web? My synced folders creates spaces in the root folder which corrupts my script.